# Prefix N and insert into select statement in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy unicode data from one table to another through SQ script. For this I have written simple SQL statement as below -

```
INSERT INTO Notes ( noteID, note ) 
SELECT eventID, eventTitle 
FROM Events;
```

note and eventTitle are NVarchar columns.

While inserting data like this unicode characters are not inserted into Notes table from Events. I see only "????" characters instead of unicode characters.

I know usually N prefix is used to insert data, but how to use N prefix here with Select statement,

Comment: You don't. If it's `nvarchar` data in both the source and destination columns, there's nothing to do. By the sound of it, that assumption is unsafe. Check your column definitions again.

Comment: Thanks Damien for quick reply, you mean to say that I dont need to do anything additional and simple insert select query as above should copy data correctly?

Comment: Yes, it **should** copy the data. There's no way to apply the `N` prefix because that's just a way to indicate "this is a unicode string literal".